# Java sort string array using Array.sort() like python's sorted with key=lambda x:

Tags: java, python, arrays, sorting

I'm occasionally learning Java. As a person from python background, I'd like to know whether there exists something like `sorted(iterable, key=function)` of python in java.

For exmaple, in python I can sort a list ordered by an element's specific character, such as

```
>>> a_list = ['bob', 'kate', 'jaguar', 'mazda', 'honda', 'civic', 'grasshopper']
>>> s=sorted(a_list) # sort all elements in ascending order first
>>> s
['bob', 'civic', 'grasshopper', 'honda', 'jaguar', 'kate', 'mazda'] 
>>> sorted(s, key=lambda x: x[1]) # sort by the second character of each element
['jaguar', 'kate', 'mazda', 'civic', 'bob', 'honda', 'grasshopper']
```

So `a_list` is sorted by ascending order first, and then by each element's 1 indexed(second) character.

My question is, if I want to sort elements by specific character in ascending order in Java, how can I achieve that?

Below is the Java code that I wrote:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class sort_list {
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String [] a_list = {"bob", "kate", "jaguar", "mazda", "honda", "civic", "grasshopper"};
    Arrays.sort(a_list);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a_list));}
  }
}
```

and the result is like this:

```
[bob, civic, grasshopper, honda, jaguar, kate, mazda]
```

Here I only achieved sorting the array in ascending order. I want the java array as the same as the python list result.

Java is new to me, so any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Comparator.comparing` to sort the list

```
Arrays.sort(a_list, Comparator.comparing(e -> e.charAt(1)));
```

And if you want to sort and collect in the new list using Java Stream API

```
String [] listSorted =  Arrays.stream(a_list)
                              .sorted(Comparator.comparing(s -> s.charAt(1)))
                              .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a custom comparator to compare two strings.

```
Arrays.sort(a_list, Comparator.comparing(s -> s.charAt(1)));
```

This compares two strings by the string's second character.

This will result in

```
[kate, jaguar, mazda, civic, bob, honda, grasshopper]
```

I see that `jaguar` and `kate` are switched in your output. I'm not sure how Python orders two String that are equal. The `Arrays.sort` does *stable* sort.

> This sort is guaranteed to be *stable*:  equal elements will
> not be reordered as a result of the sort.

Comment: This isn't equivalent. In Python, `sorted` returns a new list and leaves the original unmodified, while `Arrays.sort()` is in-place. OP doesn't use `sort`, but `sorted`, an important difference.

Comment: Then copy the original list before calling sort or use a Stream `Arrays.stream(a_list)
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(s -> s.charAt(1)))
                .toArray(String[]::new)`

Comment: Python's sorting is also stable. `jaguar` got before `kate` because `j` is smaller than `k`.

Answer (score 1):

You can supply a lambda function to [`Arrays.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator)). For your example, you could use:

```
Arrays.sort(a_list, (String a, String b) -> a.charAt(1) - b.charAt(1));
```

Assuming you have first sorted the array alphabetically (using `Arrays.sort(a_list)`) this will give you your desired result of:

```
['jaguar', 'kate', 'mazda', 'civic', 'bob', 'honda', 'grasshopper']
```